# How to evade php sanitizer function?

Tags: php, code-injection

I am using a guestbook.php code for a study on code injection. 
The trivial sanitizer function that I have used is as follows:

php echo htmlspecialchars($messages)

and have tried almost all of the different attacks from the OWASP list: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

None of those attacks were able to evade the filter.

Can someone suggest an attack which will evade this filter and get executed?

Answer (score 0):

The *context* of where such is echo'ed is important.

*If* the result of [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is ..

- placed *outside* of a complete HTML tag - meaning, *not* used for attribute values - and;
- is placed in otherwise *valid* HTML markup, where text can appear, and;
- is *outside* a SCRIPT element (or STYLE element for old IE), and;
- is *outside* a context where it can be used for a second-order attack

.. then it ought to be "safe"; with these restrictions and the operation of htmlspecialchars it is free from most of the XSS shown.

This is because it can not *enter* a malicious context by creating an unwanted HTML element due to escaping the `<`, `>`, and `&` characters. Likewise, it also cuts off XSS from the other direction as it is not possible to terminate a *quoted* HTML attribute value due the `"` and `'` escaping.

Here are some example cases when it can fail. Note that none of the characters used are 'html special' and thus it bypasses the quoting [not] performed:

```
<!-- value used directly in script context -->
<script>alert(/hacked/)</script>
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

<!-- value used as an attribute -->
<a href="javascript:alert(/hacked/)">Hello!</a>
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

<!-- if the attribute is not quoted a new attribute can be injected -->
<a id=fail href=javascript:alert(/hacked/) href=..>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```